# How to get Windows cmd to understand kubectl instead of .\kubectl

Tags: windows, kubernetes, kubectl

I am extremely new to kubernetes and am trying to get kubectl set up on local computer to connect with my aws eks cluster

However, when I try to use the CLI to do kubectl commands I have to do .\kubectl for it to work. Is there a reason for this? How can I get my windows 10 pc to understand kubectl or is there a way I can make an alias to just do something like "k" to do kubectl commands?

Not really sure where to begin.

Comment: I suspect (!?) you need to add the directory containing `kubectl` to your `PATH` environment variable. The shell searches the `PATH` for locations for binaries and you're having to override it by telling it the exact (`.` == this directory) location.  The [installation instructions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-windows/) suggest that the `kubectl` binary is installed to the current directory (whatever that was) which is curious. Generally, you'd want to install stuff in its own directory.

Comment: See e.g. [add to PATH on Windows](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/)

Comment: Thank you so much, that was it! Added the path for it in my environment variables and vallah! Thank you so much! Had no idea what I did wrong.

Comment: You're welcome! Will post as the answer for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

> From comment for posterity

I suspect (!?) you need to add the directory containing `kubectl` to your `PATH` environment variable.

The shell searches the `PATH` for locations for binaries and you're having to override it by telling it the exact (`.` == this directory) location.

The [installation instructions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-windows/) suggest that the `kubectl` binary is installed to the current directory (whatever that was) which is curious.

Generally, you'd want to install stuff in its own directory.